# Regex, catching assembler

Tags: regex

I have little problem with RegEx (I'm newbie at this).
I need to catch string where are from 1 to 6 letter at start and space or newline on end.
I tried to use:

1. http://regexpal.com/
2. http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Writing something like this:

```
.+(\s|\n)
(\w+)(\n|\s)
```

with sample data

```
cls
mov 12h,V0
jmp 123h
jmp 1234
cls
skeq
```

but it doesn't work. I need to catch:

1. cls
2. mov
3. jmp
4. skeq

Help ;[
If you have nice tutorials for RegEx to share, I will be grateful for this.

Answer (score 3):

First at all, if you want to learn regex, you can take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/

I don't know all the mnemonics of asm, and I don't know the regex engine you use (edit your post to precise it), but using this:

```
(?mi)^[a-z]{1,6}\b
```

must do the job if supported.

```
(?mi) # i make the pattern case insensitive, m make ^ means start of the line
^     # start of the line
[a-z]{1,6} # between 1 and 6 character in a-z letters
\b         # word boundary, but replacing it with (?=\h) or (?=[^\S\r\n]) will be better if possible
```

Answer (score 1):

To get what you wanna catch use

```
^(\w{1,6})(?:\s|\r?\n)?
```

with the `g` and `m` flags specified.

See the [example@regex101](http://regex101.com/r/vP2uZ4).